# Download Excel VueJS with Protected View off

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I have created a promise in Vue that returns some data that I am creating a Excel Spreadsheet with. I have the spreadsheet opening with the data populated, however it opens it in Protected View, is there any way to ensure I open it in normal view?

Here is the code

from my vuex store...

```
    exportSearch: ({commit, state, rootGetters}) => {
     return new Promise(resolve, reject) => {
      Vue.http.post(`URI PLACEHOLDER`, {responseType: "blob")
    .then((response) => {
      resolve(response);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      reject();
    })
   })
  })
```

Then in my export button

```
methods:{
 saveFile: function(){
 this.$store.dispatch('search/exportSearch')
 .then((response) => {
  let filename = (response.headers.get('Content-Disposition') || '').split('filename=')[1];
  if(filename !=== ''){
   filename = filename.replace(/['"]/g, '')
  }
  let link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
  link.download = filename
  document.body.appendChild(link)
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link)
}
```

Comment: Excel Protected View is a client side setting set in the Trust Center (more info here: http://www.corporatefocus.com/support/how-to-disable-protected-view-in-microsoft-excel) - to be able to disable Protected View either from within the file or by external code would be incredibly insecure. I'm thinking the answer is 'no' here.

Comment: I understand why that would be for public internet, but for a private network I can't avoid this?

Comment: The only way you could override this on a private network is if you're a network administrator and have permissions to do so (likely with Group Policy). I have worked as tech support near this sort of configuration (enterprise eDiscovery processing), but making such changes was out of my scope, so I'm not certain of the process. BE WARNED: If you disable Protected View in your network, and someone opens a malicious file, it's game on for whatever's in that file.

More info on disabling via GPO: https://serverfault.com/questions/484480/can-ms-office-protected-view-be-disabled-via-gpo